# Формат даты через точки, неправильно выводит даты

Tags: php, mysql, sql

У меня в MySQL более 30 тысяч пользователей, у которых дата регистрации в формате "30.10.2016 12:30:00".

Мне сейчас нужно сделать сортировку по датам.

Использую: `WHERE date BETWEEN дата1 AND дата2`

Все отлично работает только для одного месяца, если сортирую между месяцами, то ничего не выводит. Например:

`WHERE date BETWEEN 29.10.2016 13:00:00 AND 01.11.2016 13:00:00`

Проблема скорее всего в формате даты, сравниваются только дни?! Точку нужно заменить на тире, и тогда все заработает (скорее всего).

Но как это сделать? Менять код в скрипте нет желания, менять формат даты у 30 тыс. пользователей тоже не айс.

Как быть? Есть конвертер формата в MySQL? Или может можно как-то по-другому сравнивать между датами?

Comment: поле, в котором хранится дата какого типа(дата или текст)?

Comment: @lDrakonl текст

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в поле хранится строка. По этому когда вы сравниваете, происходит сравнивание строк, а не дат. При таком формате месяцы и годы будт учитываться только для одного и того же числа. Замена точек на тире проблему не решит. Надо приводить значение к дате. Используйте функцию [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)
Выглядеть это будет так:

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d.%m.%Y') BETWEEN 
STR_TO_DATE('29.10.2016', '%d.%m.%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('01.11.2016', '%d.%m.%Y')
```